# Angular 4 - Bindings cannot contain assignments

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to get a css selector as `@Input` in my component.
so I have to write something as the following for passing a css selector:

```
<mds-datetime-picker [inLine]="true" [targetSelector]='[data-name="target"]'></mds-datetime-picker>
```

But it throws `Bindings cannot contain assignments` in `[targetSelector]='[data-name="target"]'`
How can I dot it?

Comment: What is that binding supposed to do?

Comment: Actually, I'm writing a date-time picker, so I want to get a css selector to fill 
 it with selected date

Comment: So you want to pass `[data-name="target"]` as string. My answer below shows how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is

```
[targetSelector]='\"[data-name="target"]\"'
```

or

```
targetSelector='[data-name="target"]'
```

to pass the value as string instead of as expression.

Comment: Great, I test `targetSelector='[data-name="target"]'` and worked :)